# jQuery hover, onhover show another element and move the mouse back

Tags: javascript, jquery

When on hover the red box, the grey box will show up. if the mouse stay on grey box, the grey box stays opened. When move the mouse from grey box back to the red box, I want to have the grey box still opened.

Grey box only closes when mouse is not hovered on red or grey box.

http://jsfiddle.net/0sLhL0xf/

The only problem is that, when I move mouse from grey box back to red box, I can't get grey stayed to show.

Can someone please help? please do not change structure, I understand to have box2 wrapped by box1 is easier,

```
<div id="box1">
    <div id="box2"></div>
</div>
```

but this isn't what I wanted to try. Thanks

Comment: Can include `js` tried at Question ?

Comment: Do you need the timeouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use

```js
var timeout;
var $box1 = $('#box1');
var $box2 = $('#box2');

$box1.hover(function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  $box2.show();
}, function() {
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $box2.hide();
  }, 1000);
});

$box2.hover(function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}, function() {
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $box2.hide();
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#box1 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#box2 {
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing `css`

```css
#box1 {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#box2 {
    display:none;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: grey;
}

#box1:hover + #box2, #box2:hover {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0sLhL0xf/3/

Comment: Thanks! however if the structure changed to `<div id="mybox">
 <div id="mybox_layer">
       <div id="box1"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="box2"></div>` then css won't work

Comment: @olo Perhaps update original post details ,  jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0sLhL0xf/ at Question to reflect possibility of `html` above ? fwiw, `css` , adjusted slighly , could possibly return same results with above `html` . Cheers:)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution using `mouseenter` & `mouseleave`.

http://jsfiddle.net/0sLhL0xf/2/

```js
var $boxes = $('.boxes');
var $box1 = $('#box1');
var $box2 = $('#box2');

$boxes.mouseenter(function() {
    $box2.show();
});
$boxes.mouseleave(function() {
    $box2.hide();
});
```

```css
#box1 {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#box2 {
    display:none;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes" id="box1"></div>
<div class="boxes" id="box2"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Post the code here, not just in a fiddle. Why don't you use a stack snippet so the code here will be executable like a fiddle?

Comment: @Barmar my bad, snippet added.